# Когда лучше использовать хранимые процедуры или представления

Tags: sql, sql-server

Объясните, пожалуйста, когда лучше использовать процедуру а когда представление?
И что здесь может быть общего(взаимозаменяемого), что различного?

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо использовать представления в следующих случаях:

- Упрощения и настройки восприятия информации (объединить сложный запрос в представление)
- Большая безопасность (нет непосредственного доступа к таблицам)
- Обратная совместимость (таблица существует, но схема изменилась)

Необходимо использовать хранимые процедуры в следующих случаях:

- Снижение сетевого трафика между клиентами и сервером (по сети отправляется только вызов на выполнение процедуры)
- Большая безопасность (не видно имен объектов таблиц и баз данных, невозможность внедрять свои инструкции)
- Более легкое обслуживание (для внесения изменений в основную базу данных будет достаточно обновить только процедуры)
- Повышение производительности (обработчику запросов не нужно создавать новый план, обычно обработка процедуры занимает меньше времени)

Comment: Также процедуры могут содержать более сложную логику. Например, синтезировать часть данных по значениям входных параметров или ячеек таблицы.